# How to Register new Member through XMPP?

Tags: android

I am working over a chat application but there is a problem that i am not able to register new members to the chat through XMPP.

Please anyone assist me and if possible provide code for that activity.

fetchAvtar file...

```
public byte[] fetchAvatar(RosterEntry entry) {
    if (isAuthenticated()) {
        String user;
        if (entry == null)
            user = this.username;
        else
            user = entry.getUser();
        VCard card = new VCard();//it will give error
        try {
            card.load(connection, user);

            byte[] result = card.getAvatar();
            return result;
        } catch (XMPPException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public class RegistrationActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

private Button mRegister;

private static final String TALK_SERVER = "jandeccpl.com";
private static final int TALK_PORT = 5222;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_registration);

    /*
     * setFont(RegistrationActivity.this, mName, mEmail, mPassword,
     * mConfirmPassword);
     * 
     * setFont(RegistrationActivity.this, mRegister);
     */

    mRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mRegister);
    mRegister.setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    super.onBackPressed();
    RegistrationActivity.this.finish();
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub


    new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            ConnectionConfiguration connConfig = new ConnectionConfiguration(
                    TALK_SERVER, TALK_PORT);
            XMPPConnection connection = new XMPPConnection(connConfig);
            AccountManager createUserAccount = connection
                    .getAccountManager();

            try {
                connection.connect();
                Map<String, String> attributes = new HashMap<String, String>();
                attributes.put("Name", "ABC");
                createUserAccount.createAccount("asdf",
                        "Password", attributes);
                Log.e("", "created");
            } catch (XMPPException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    }).start();

  }
}
```

and put internet permission in manifest file

Comment: Because Right Now I am Working on the same app and i have done that.

Comment: createUserAccount.createAccount("adminCreated1",
                "Password", attributes);  what i have entered in place of  admincreated1 and Password...

Comment: put this permission in manifest file<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

Comment: for the first time it will create the account but on the second time it will give exception because you cant create account with the same name twice... just remember to handle it.

Comment: This Code is 100% working i have checked it by my self and if i gives you trouble then i am here you can contact me freely

Comment: attributes.put("Name", "ABC");
                createUserAccount.createAccount("asdf",
                        "Password", attributes);     Just explain these two lines what exactly we pass here.

Comment: createUserAccount.createAccount("ASDF","pASSWORD",ATTRIBUTE), that line create user with userName (ASDF) AND PASSWORD (pASSWORD) And have that attribute that can contain its email and the name , that name is different from userName

Comment: And if that answer is usefull to you then accept the answer... :)

Comment: when i am login with new register member it login to server but give :- remote-server-not-found(404)
at org.jivesoftware.smackx.packet.VCard.doLoad(VCard.java:568)
at org.jivesoftware.smackx.packet.VCard.load(VCard.java:551)
at com.example.whatsapp.xmpp.ChatController.fetchAvatar(ChatController.java:306)
at com.example.whatsapp.xmpp.ThreadLoadAvatars.run(ThreadLoadAvatars.java:48)

Comment: What library you are using ?

Comment: aSmack library i m using